# How to check data present or not in html id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have a HTML paragraph, if it is empty I want to show alert using jquery how.? I have tried the following:

```js
var abc= $("#foo").text();
var abc= $("#foo").data();
var abc= $("#foo").val();

if (abc== '') { alert('working'); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="foo"></p>
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you've tried? it works.

Comment: Yes, this is working...

Comment: it is working with length actually I'm checking table tr present or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is used to retrieve the value of an `input`, not the text node value of an element. [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) is used to retrieve data values for an element, not its text node value.

To check if the element **does not contain anything**, you should used [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/). It's also worth noting that you may (or may not) need to use [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) to ignore whitespace, and to also check for child elements that do not have any text using [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/):

```js
var $p    = $('#foo'),
    empty = ($.trim($p.text()) == '' && !$p.children().length);

console.log(empty);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="foo"></p>
```

---

Better still though, rather than rolling your own function for this, you can use jQuery's [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function, coupled with the [`:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) selector:

```js
console.log( $('#foo').is(':empty') );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="foo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
var abc = $("#foo").text()
if(!abc) {
alert('not working');
} else {
    alert('working');
}
```